# Long running scheduled executor in Java

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I am getting started on Java concurrency features and while here at the interface [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). I came across this snippet that makes a beep every 10 secs for a hour:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
 class BeeperControl {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
       Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void beepForAnHour() {
        final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
                public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
            };
        final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
        scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
            }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
    }
 }
```

This seemed easy for starters like me, but my problem is that I want a Java program that reads a MySql table every 10 seconds forever. Is a scheduled executor the best choice for this sort of work?

Comment: Yes. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: The `ScheduledExecutorService` is what your want, but with the method `scheduleAtFixedRate()` or `scheduleWithFixedDelay()` instead of `schedule()`

Comment: Just remove the last schedule, which cancels the task, and it will run forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run forever, take out the code to cancel the task.